# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document php

Tags: php, soap, web-services

I'm trying to make a SOAP web service work.
I have a XAMPP server installed and I use Visual Studio Code for coding. I've created a **web service** in a file called "servidorWs.php'. Its content is the following:

```
function sumar($n1, $n2){
    return $n1+$n2;
}
function restar($n1, $n2){
     return $n1+$n2;
}

$uri ="localhost/34curso";
$servidor = new SoapServer(null, array('uri'=>$uri));

$servidor->addFunction("sumar");
$servidor->addFunction("restar");
$servidor->handle();

echo "Servidor de servicios web SOAP funcionando.";
```

And also I've created a **web service consumer** in the file "consumidorWs.php" with the following code:

> Blockquote

//Al no especificar el wsdl del servicio web, debemos detallar el url donde 
 vamos a consumir el servicio

```
 $url="http://localhost/34curso/servidorWs.php";
   $uri="http://localhost/34curso/";

   //Creamos el cliente con el segundo parámetro. El primero null 
   $cliente = new SoapClient(null, array('location'=>$url, 'uri'=>$uri));

   $numero = $cliente->sumar(5,4);
   echo "valor de la suma ".$numero."<br/>";

   $numero = $cliente->restar(5,4);
   echo "valor de la resta ".$resta;
```

> Blockquote

I call the webserver in Google Chrome and apparently it works.
But when I execute the client I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got
>   no XML document in ...consumidorWs.php:9 Stack trace: #0 ...
>   consumidorWs.php(9): SoapClient->__call('sumar', Array) #1 {main}
>   thrown in ...consumidorWs.php on line 9.

Can anybody help me?
Is it necessary to do anything to make the server works? I tried executing in the Terminal with no difference.

Thank you.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon and thank you very much for your corrections.

Finally I get to an answer. The line `"echo "Servidor de servicios web SOAP funcionando.;"` was responsible for the error.

I remove it and it works almost perfectly. The "restar" function doesn't work correctly but it was a logic mistake.

```
function restar($n1, $n2){
     return $n1+$n2;
}
```

instead of ...

```
function restar($n1, $n2){
     return $n1-$n2;
}
```

And also ...

```
$numero = $cliente->restar(5,4);
echo "valor de la resta ".$resta;
```

... was wrong.

The right code:

```
$numero = $cliente->restar(5,4);
echo "valor de la resta ".$numero;
```

Thank you to everyone that tried to help me.

Best wishes.

Comment: if this is the answer, then please accept it to indicate that